# Magento - Why Can't I Use getAttributeText in Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

Whenever I use in Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php

`$handlingtime = $this->getProduct()->getAttributeText('fig_handling_time');`

I get this error when sending a new order email through my admin or testing through my site

`Fatal error: Call to a member function getAttributeText() on a non-object in /home/japena/public_html/app/code/local/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php on line 1336`

I'm trying to access the `fig_handling_time` attribute for the product being purchased.

I use `fig_handling_time` to display an estimated shipping and delivery time in the frontend product page, but I also want to display this in the order email.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if I understand your problem correctly but you want to get attribute from products of this order ? In order you can have more than one product, and the code to get all of them is:

```
$items = $order->getAllItems();
```

So in this case:

```
$items = $this->getAllItems();
```

After that you can iterate through them:

```
foreach ($items as $itemId => $item)
{
  $item->getProduct()->getAttributeText('fig_handling_time');
}
```

Comment: I got it `$items = $this->getAllItems();

foreach ($items as $itemId => $item)
{
  $handlingtime = $item->getProduct()->getAttributeText('fig_handling_time');
}`